# What is "[BLOB - ...]" shown in SQL database column?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm working on an SQL database via PHPmyAdmin and i have a column called pagesText, it supposed to show some text but all i see is "[BLOB - ...]".

[image: snapshot of the table column]

what is this? and how can i get the original text?

Comment: Check this http://googleitfor.me/?q=blob+mysql

Comment: It says BLOB because PHPMyAdmin doesn't want to display 6.4KiB of text in that tiny space...

Comment: No , it says "BLOB" instead of showing any content because it could *possibly* contain non-printable bytes. That's what "BLOB" means: "*b*inary *l*arge *ob*ject".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on Options, tick "Show BLOB contents" and click on Go.

Answer (score 0):

About Blob:

From Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object

> A blob (alternately known as a binary large object, basic large
>   object, BLOB, or BLOb) is a collection of binary data stored as a
>   single entity in a database management system. Blobs are typically
>   images, audio or other multimedia objects, though sometimes binary
>   executable code is stored as a blob. Database support for blobs is not
>   universal.

Basically what it means is that your data is saved in binary format directly. (all data is binary, I know.)

But, you can simply access the field via your code in PHP and can manipulate, `echo` it easily.

PhpMyAdmin shows it as BLOB here, since it does not want to show long texts in record tables.

Comment: can i edit its contents ?

Comment: have you uploaded a file which was stored as a blob?

Answer (score 0):

Your text has been stored as binary data, see wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object

Read also [phpmyadmin shows numbers or blob for mysql's utf8_bin callation columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721302/phpmyadmin-shows-numbers-or-blob-for-mysqls-utf8-bin-callation-columns)