# edit phpmyadmin blob field

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Huh.

In the same vein as [Viewing Content Of Blob In phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188264/viewing-content-of-blob-in-phpmyadmin), i have a blob.

And just like in the screenshot of the  given url, it says "blob". Thanks, phpmyadmin! You're the best!

Unlike the chap who asked the question above, though, I really want to *edit* the blob values, and then save them. So, if my blob has, as its text "ima blob yo" - and I *can* see that text, thanks to the solution given above - how do i edit that to "i am a blob, you".

I don't particularly want to upload a text file each time i edit a blob, that's totes bogue. Just want to edit it, as i would a text field.

cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah. the phpmyadmin site, there this page: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#faq1_31

```
$cfg['ProtectBinary'] boolean or string
Defines whether BLOB or BINARY columns are protected from editing when browsing a table's content. Valid values are:

    * FALSE to allow editing of all columns;
    * 'blob' to allow editing of all columns except BLOBS;
    * 'all' to disallow editing of all BINARY or BLOB columns.
```

Ok, so that details how to allow me to edit my blobs.

I made the change

```
$cfg['ProtectBinary'] = FALSE;
$cfg['ShowBlob'] = TRUE;
```

and put these two as the last lines in my `config.inc.php` file, which, because i'm using UBUNTU and used the auto install `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`, was at `/etc/phpmyadmin/`

And everything worked, kinda. I can now edit my blobs... with the limitation that phpmyadmin shows the current contents of the blob in "blob-view", which is a whole bunch of numbers or some nonsense.

Simple solution i found was to:

1. write over the text. Simple editing isn't really an option, but luckily i didn't need to edit, just add in new data.
2. change the "function" option from ... i cannot remember what it was, but it was something crazy... to just "blank". That's the same kind of blank as the function option defaults for other values - ints etc

cheers,
andrew

PS that

```
$cfg['ShowBlob'] = TRUE;
```

was from the given url in the question i linked to. The poster states it isn't effective in phpmyadmin, but i only downloaded using a latest sudo-get a few months back, so it still works. Actually, i *needed* to put that value in to get editing to work.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using **phpMyAdmin v4.6.4**. I find an option on GUI to set this config.

You can click on **Home** button. Then click on **Panel Appearance settings**.
In this screen, click on **Main panel** tab, then **Edit mode** tab.
After that, select **'no'** in **Protect binary columns** dropdown.

[Edit mode tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqC5U.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for this and for adding the picture too! In v4.9.7, you go to **Home -> Settings -> Main panel -> Edit mode**. When the "**Protect binary columns**" was set to "**no**", the blobs were now editable as text, but they were in hex format. I could however confirm from my hex editor (HxD Hex Editor) that it translated to the required ASCII text.

Comment: I also did a bit of experiment and realized that even with the BLOBs editing protected, I could **edit the downloaded binary (.bin)** files in HxD, and then **re-upload**, and the changes I made were reflected. Finally, you could also easily change (update) the BLOB values **using SQL commands**. For example `UPDATE your_table_name SET val = 'the string value to set' WHERE name = 'the_field_name'`

Answer (score 2):

If your BLOB field is really only text, then you might consider converting your BLOB field to a TEXT field (there should be no loss of data in the process). TEXT fields are viewable/editable directly from phpMyAdmin.