# HOW to SHOW BLOB FILES (jpeg) in phpmyadmin 3.5.

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have tried all means of showing my `blob` images alongside my other fields but to no avail. All I get is some gibberish writing. I need help serious. Cos I'm on a project. 
I tried pasting `column table`, `browse MIME`, etc. inside the `config.inc.php` file but to no success. I need someone to walk me through step by step into the configuration.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure whether phpMyAdmin can show blob fields as images in the first place?

Comment: More Database processing = less speed, I think you want to store the image in your database[in your project]. If yes then you have bad idea, Good Idea is "Upload a file to server + save its link in database ". And Php My Admin is just an MySql client so not sure if you can view stored image  [bolb].

Answer (score 1):

See [Viewing Content Of Blob In phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188264/viewing-content-of-blob-in-phpmyadmin) for more details, but basically what it boils down to is that you cannot view the rendered image directly from phpMyAdmin. The gibberish writing that you're seeing is the binary representation of your image files. This is expected behavior, since the BLOB field (and phpMyAdmin) has no knowledge of what the binary data represents.

Comment: Thanks guys. Really appreciate it. I need to ask one more question. How do I enable fully the features of phpmyadmin such as transformations etc. I need a sample of the a fully config.inc.pho file so that I can copy and paste. I read I phpmyadmin 3.4 book how to do it but, the configurations are too complicated. has this ever worked for anyone? If it does help out and let's make phpmyadmin better

Comment: Steve, nobody can provide you a "full" config. There are values that are inherently different, based on your specific set up. The config file is fully commented, and explains each configuration option. If you have a specific question about a specific config option, that probably would be better suited asking here. Otherwise, make a copy of the config before editing, and just try out different values to see how they impact the installation. Otherwise, I'd strongly recommend hiring somebody with more experience to help set it up (always check references!).

Comment: guys thanks so much. i finaly figured out how to display BLOB images in phpmyadmin. in case someone need how to do it, send me an email and i will show you step by step. alornyostephen@rocketmail.com