# Two tables, whit one to many relationship. How to join values without duplicate rows?

Tags: mysql, database, pdo

I've a table called "messages" and another one called "votations". Each message can have more than one vote, The problem that actually they are placed in different rows.How can i Fix it?

The actual query is:

```
SELECT messages.ID, votations.value
FROM messages 
LEFT JOIN votations ON messages.ID=votations.messageID
```

[image]

Comment: Funny, you did it the right way and now you want the wrong way solution. Why? What do you get if you have votes displayed as columns? What's wrong with how it works currently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do this purely in MySQL. In the result set you can't have rows with different (number of) columns. You need some application logic implemented. The closest you can get to this is:

```
select m.id, GROUP_CONCAT(voto SEPARATOR ',') 
from messages m 
left join votations v on v.messageID = m.id
group by m.id;
```

This will return this format:

```
ID  GROUP_CONCAT(VOTO SEPARATOR ',')
1   2,5,6
2   2,12,3
```

You can see this working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/241a8/3

Comment: It's ok, but won't work in my project.. I've this result on 69 ID:
69 [BLOB - 5 B]

Comment: In which case try casting voto to a different (string) datatype before concatenating it (what data type is voto currently).

Comment: Did you try this in phpmyadmin? Check out the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188264/viewing-content-of-blob-in-phpmyadmin

Comment: Actually voto is decimal(10,0) type... So i have to set it as TEXT?

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT is to concatenate strings together. I suspect that MySQL has defaulted to converting the field to a blob before concatenating them. Leave the field as a decimal, but do the CAST within the GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: Why is it decimal if you don't expect to have decimals? Wouldn't it be easier to use tinyint (only 1 byte)?

Comment: By the way. MySQL does every casting necessary internally for you. You don't need to do anything. BLOB - 5B is just the representation of the value. Probably if you do it in your application you won't experience the same and everything will be just fine. (The mysql connectors take care of MySQL type to variable type casting too).

Comment: anyway my objective is to calculate the average valutation (sum of valutation/total valutations). Is it possibile thrrought the same query or i've to do it manually with successive php scripting?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. The query for the averages would be:

select m.id, AVG(voto) as average_valuation
from messages m 
left join votations v on v.messageID = m.id
group by m.id;