# BLOB field is cut when download using phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Raw mysql-client: (Good)

```
mysql> SELECT blobfield FROM `mytable` WHERE `id` = 46361 ;
{"example":"日本語...", "everything": "ok"}
```

phpMyAdmin > Export > SQL: (Good)

```
(46361, 0x7b226578616d706c65223a223f3f3f2e2e2e222c202265766572797468696e67223a20226f6b227d);
```

phpMyAdmin > Browse > Click over BLOB field: (Fail. Only partial-saved)

```
{"example":"日本語...", "everythi
```

(edit) curl (phpMyAdmin request):

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:48001/tbl_get_field.php?db=develop&table=mytable&where_clause=%60mytable%60.%60id%60+%3D+46361&transform_key=data&sql_query=SELECT+id%2Cdata+FROM+%60mytable%60+WHERE+id%3D46361&token=removed' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0'
{"example":"日本語...", "everythi
```

(edit2) (In verbose mode I found an error...)

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server nginx/1.6.2 is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.6.2
< Date: Mon, 13 Apr 2015 10:45:08 GMT
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: **6453**
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.22-1~dotdeb.1
< Expires: Mon, 13 Apr 2015 10:45:08 +0000
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate,  pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0
< Pragma: no-cache
< Last-Modified: Mon, 13 Apr 2015 10:45:08 +0000
< Content-Description: File Transfer
< Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="mytable-data.bin"
< Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

 * Excess found in a non pipelined read: excess = **1338**, size = 6453, maxdownload = 6453, bytecount = 0 .
```

Is anybody having the same issue? I guess that phpMyAdmin is sending a wrong Content-Length value.

My configuration:

- Mysql: 5.6.23-log
- phpMyAdmin: 4.4.1.1
- connection: utf8mb4_bin (auto-switch from utf8_bin)
- innodb: utf8_bin
- nginx/1.7.9
- php: 5.6.4-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 + mysqli

Comment: possible duplicate of [Viewing Content Of Blob In phpMyAdmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188264/viewing-content-of-blob-in-phpmyadmin)

Comment: I don't want to view the content, I want to download it. The problem is not related as here I got corrupted data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In file "tbl_get_field.php" I found:

```
PMA_downloadHeader(
    $table . '-' .  $_GET['transform_key'] . '.bin',
    PMA_detectMIME($result),
    /*overload*/mb_strlen($result)
);
```

Last line calculate using internal mb_internal_encoding() the total length. In my case, it's set to UTF-8.

Changing to:

```
/*overload*/mb_strlen($result, '8bit')
```

solved my problem. Info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php#77040

Line added into my Dockerfile:

```
RUN sed -i.bak s/mb_strlen\(\$result\)/mb_strlen\(\$result,\'8bit\'\)/g /data/http/tbl_get_field.php
```