# Why does my data upload doesn't work and doesn't drop any errors?

Tags: php, upload

I am trying to build a little upload script which uploads data as a blob to my database. I made a really simple form like that:

```
<form action="admin.php" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="datei">
     <br>
     <input type="submit" value="Upload!">
 </form>
```

And my PHP File as that:

```
if (isset($_FILES["datei"]) && isset($_FILES["datei"]["tmp_name"]) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES["datei"]["tmp_name"])) {
    try {
        $con = new MySQLi("localhost", "tom", "DBdb123#", "db");
        if ($con) {
            $name = basename($_FILES["datei"]["tmp_name"]);
            $datei = $_FILES["datei"];

            $sql = "INSERT INTO dateien (name, datei) VALUES (?, ?)";
            $kommando = $db->prepare($sql);
            $kommando->bind_param("sb", $name, $datei);

            try {
                $kommando->execute();
                echo "Upload erfolgreich!";
            } catch(Exception $ex) {
                echo "Fehler: " . $ex->getMessage() . "!";
            }
            $db->close();
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo "Fehler: " . $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

So I request a error message after both `try`'s but after a test, nothing happened. No error, no successfull message, no database entry.. just as I didn't click/upload anything. I am trying this for an hour now and nothing changes.. that's really frustrating.

Comment: you need 'enctype="multipart/form-data"' in your FORM

Comment: What is the first `if` fails? You get nothing. So I'd look into that.

Comment: ALso `$datei = $_FILES["datei"];` wil set `$datei` to an array, which WONT work with `$kommando->bind_param("sb", $name, $datei);
`

Comment: Also I assume as the file column is defined as a blob, you are trying to store the file onto the database and not just the path to it on the file system. This means you will need to read the file, so you can store it

Comment: @RiggsFolly Mhh alright, adding that form-data attribute to the form made the process work and display errors. You're right, I am using a blob column, I'll have to learn how to read a file etc. Thank you, sir!

Comment: try `$datei  = file_get_content($_FILES["datei"]["tmp_name"]);`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Mhh it didn't drop any errors (after adding a "s" to content) but the blob field seems to keep empty in the "phpmyadmin"-view.

Comment: Have a read on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188264/viewing-content-of-blob-in-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

You should mention `enctype="multipart/form-data` in your code when uploading files.

**Change your code to**

```
<form action="admin.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="datei">
     <br>
     <input type="submit" value="Upload!">
 </form>
```

Comment: Only one of MANY issues I am afraid

Comment: Which issues i didn't get you?